# How can I update a vector item in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

Given:

```
(def my-vec [{:id 0 :a "foo" :b "bar"} {:id 1 :a "baz" :b "spam"} 
             {:id 2 :a "qux" :b "fred"}])
```

How can I idiomatically update * the item in my-vec with `:id=1` to have values `:a="baz2"` and `:b="spam2"`?

<sub>*:  I recognize that I wouldn't actually be updating my-vec, but really returning a new vector that is identical to my-vec except for the replacement values.</sub>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

map a function over the vector of maps that either creates a modified map if the key matches or uses the original if the keys don't match then turn the result back into a vector

```
(vec (map #(if (= (:id %) 1) 
             (assoc % :a "baz2" :b "spam2")
             %)))
```

It is possible to do this more succinctly though this one really shows where the structural sharing occurs.

Answer (score 10):

Do you know ahead of time that the map with id == 1 is the second map in your vector?  If so:

```
user> (-> my-vec
          (assoc-in [1 :a] "baz2")
          (assoc-in [1 :b] "spam2"))
[{:id 0, :a "foo", :b "bar"} {:id 1, :a "baz2", :b "spam2"} {:id 2, :a "qux", :b "fred"}]
```

If you need to access your data by id a lot, another idea is to replace your vector of hash-maps with a hash-map of hash-maps keyed on `:id`.  Then you can more easily `assoc-in` no matter the order of things.

```
user> (def new-my-vec (zipmap (map :id my-vec) my-vec))
#'user/new-my-vec
user> new-my-vec
{2 {:id 2, :a "qux", :b "fred"}, 1 {:id 1, :a "baz", :b "spam"}, 0 {:id 0, :a "foo", :b "bar"}}
user> (-> new-my-vec
          (assoc-in [1 :a] "baz2")
          (assoc-in [1 :b] "spam2"))
{2 {:id 2, :a "qux", :b "fred"}, 1 {:id 1, :a "baz2", :b "spam2"}, 0 {:id 0, :a "foo", :b "bar"}}
```

Comment: Hmm. I store it in a vector because what I'm actually holding is ImageIcons of playing cards and the vector position winds up acting as a z-order when I draw. [{:id "8H" :image ImageIcon} ...]. But I might be able to store them in a map {{:id "8H" :z-order 2 :image ImageIcon}...} and then Graphics.draw them by pulling them out by their sorted :z-order. Thanks, Brian, you're a Clojure monster. :)

Comment: `(update-in my-vec [1] assoc :a "baz2" :b "spam2")` seems much cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

Might want to take a look at [array-map](http://richhickey.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/array-map) which creates a map backed by an array and keyed by the index instead of using :id?